# ASIFormDataRequest works on simulator but not on device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, simulator, asiformdatarequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest to post three values which are a url, a title and a summary. All of them works fine on simulator but its not working on device. Here are the code that I'm using:

```
- (IBAction)addLinkPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    ASIFormDataRequest *loginRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyWebsite.com/login.php"]];
    [loginRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [loginRequest setPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"defaultUsername"] forKey:@"username"];
    [loginRequest setPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"defaultPassword"] forKey:@"password"];
    [loginRequest setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    [loginRequest setDelegate:self];

    [loginRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestLoginFinished:)];
    [loginRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestLoginFailed:)];
    [loginRequest startSynchronous];



    NSString *strURL = @"http://MyWebsite.com/send_link.php";
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:self.linkField.text forKey:@"url"];
    [request setPostValue:self.linkTitleField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [request setPostValue:self.linkSummaryField.text forKey:@"summary"];

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Anybody can help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: ASIRequest is not anymore supported. It is known to be buggy in some cases and that bugs won't be fixed.

Second one, regarding your question, I see two places where error could occur (difference between simulator and device):

1. Are you sure that on device `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"defaultUsername"]` and `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"defaultPassword"]` are set properly?
2. On iOS simulator you have not got access to keychain so this setting (`[loginRequest setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];`) could cause problems on the device too.

I advice to check `NSUserDefaults` and better use another one framework, i.e. RestKit

**EDITED:**

Example of using RestKit:

```
[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://example.com"];
RKClient *rkclient = [RKClient sharedClient];
RKParams *params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   username, @"username",
                                                   password, @"password", nil]];
[rkclient post:@"/profile" params:params delegate:self];

// implement needed delegate methods
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you said ASIRequest is not supported anymore, what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Thank you, I installed the RestKit. My last question: If I want to write codes to do the same thing that I did for ASIRequest, what is your suggestion code for RestKit? I read many tutorials but I confused which one is the best for my application.