# Post on website works on simulator but not on device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I want to use the web service in my app and upload post on the website, at first I used ASIFormRequest API, it worked on simulator but did not work on device, I asked a question here and someone told me to change the API and use the RestKit ([Here is the link for my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241889/asiformdatarequest-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device))

Right now I'm using RestKit API and I got the same problem, I cannot post on the website by device, but It works when I use simulator. Although it doesn't allow me to post but I can login both by the simulator and the device.

Here is my code for POST:

```
- (IBAction)addLinkPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://MyWebsite.com"];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            self.linkField.text, @"url",
                            self.linkTitleField.text, @"title",
                            self.linkSummaryField.text, @"summary",
                            nil];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/send_link.php" params:params delegate:self];

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSRange range = [[error localizedDescription] rangeOfString:@"-1012"];
    if (range.length > 0){
        //Do whatever here to handle authentication failures
    }
    RKLogError(@"Hit error: %@", error);
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response
{
    if ([request isGET]) {
        // Handling GET /foo.xml

        if ([response isOK]) {
            // Success! Let's take a look at the data
            NSLog(@"Retrieved XML: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        }

    } else if ([request isPOST]) {

        // Handling POST /other.json
        if ([response isJSON]) {
            NSLog(@"Got a JSON response back from our POST!");
        }

    } else if ([request isDELETE]) {

        // Handling DELETE /missing_resource.txt
        if ([response isNotFound]) {
            NSLog(@"The resource path '%@' was not found.", [request resourcePath]);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"HTTP status code:     %d", response.statusCode);
    NSLog(@"HTTP status message:  %@", [response localizedStatusCodeString]);
    NSLog(@"Header fields: %@", response.allHeaderFields);
    NSLog(@"Body: %@", response.bodyAsString);
}
```

Here is the error that I receive for RestKit API:

```
    2012-09-11 22:33:01.053 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] I restkit.support:RKCache.m:189 Invalidating cache at path: /var/mobile/Applications/897B1DEA-1767-4F5C-AC8F-1809075C5CA9/Library/Caches/RKClientRequestCache-(Mywebsite).com/SessionStore
    2012-09-11 22:33:01.057 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:123 Reachability observer initialized with IP address: 0.0.0.0.
    2012-09-11 22:33:01.075 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:391 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x10066330 host=0.0.0.0
2012-09-11 22:33:01.075 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:391 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x10066330 host=0.0.0.0 isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=NO reachabilityFlags=-R -----l->
2012-09-11 22:33:01.325 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:689 Status Code: 200
2012-09-11 22:33:01.328 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] HTTP status code:     200
2012-09-11 22:33:01.332 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] HTTP status message:  no error
2012-09-11 22:33:01.338 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] Header fields: {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 4679;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Wed, 12 Sep 2012 03:33:02 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
}
2012-09-11 22:33:01.345 (NameOfMyApp)[16271:707] Body: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Ater these code, it shows the HTML code of the address that I use for POST ( http://MyWebsite.com/send_link.php)

Any Idea how can would be appreciated, I really need help :(

Comment: Have you implimented didFailLoadWithError method of RKRequestDelegate, and in this method print decription of error, it will be better if you provide what exact error you are getting, also provide some code if possible.

Comment: @prasad thanks for your comment, I edited my question and add the error that I receive, I would appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Can you show how you make the POST call and how you set up RestKit with your web service's base URL?

Comment: @danielbeard I edited my question and add the code that I use for POST, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What is happening that you aren't expecting? It's giving a status code of `200 OK`.

Comment: @danielbeard Yes But it does nothing, When I go to the website, It doesn't show the post that I sent via application, but when I do the same process by simulator it POSTs on website.

Comment: @danielbeard Every time I want to POST by simulator I have to login, do you how can I save username and password and make it persistence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, In simulator it doesn't need to put http:// at the beginning of the url addresses, but on device, if I do not input http:// the website that I use their web service doesn't allow me to POST. Isn't that weird!
Thank you guys for your comments.
One more thing is, when I close the app and reopen it I have to do login, any idea how I can make the username and password persistence?

Comment: Have a look at the keychain. SSKeycahin makes this easy, but this really belongs in a separate question.